# Picklists not Supported in SOQL WHERE Clause (External Objects)

Tags: soql, picklist, lightning-connect

**Background**

I ran a SOQL query from the developer console on one of my external objects which has a picklist field (Object name **Fixture__x**, picklist field name **Status__c**).

The following query:

`SELECT Id, Status__c from Fixture__x`

returns a couple of records with a status of `Scheduled`:

[image]

Then I tried:

`SELECT Id, Status__c FROM Fixture__x WHERE Status__c = 'Scheduled'`

The Query editor threw an error:

> sObject type 'Fixture__x' is not supported.

However, if I execute the very same query in APEX, I get no errors, rather this debug log:

[image]

**Conclusion**

Picklists aren't supported in the SOQL WHERE clause for external objects.

**Question(s)**

Is this documented anywhere? Any reason why they aren't supported? Is there anything I'm missing or it needs to be done differently in order to achieve this? Aren't the picklists treated as strings (text) anyway?

Answer (score 7):

I suspect this might be down to how they're implemented on the external system itself. The where part of the query is not handled by Salesforce, but by the OData compliant API at the other end, the where basically defines a query for the REST response.

Dynamics CRM uses text based labels for what we know as picklists, but then has integers for the actual values stored in the database; so I suspect what is happening is that Salesforce doesn't allow such queries to be made because implementation details would vary. If Salesforce sends a text value to Dynamics that's not going to match on the other end, and I don't believe Salesforce have processing in place to import such values from the other system when configuring the object.

I could be completely wrong of course :)

Comment: Thing is, you create a custom field on the external object on the Salesforce end, I would imagine the way it's stored on the external system, should be determined by Salesforce. Also it would've been nice if it was documented as a consideration when implementing such functionality. (For an example it could be stated here - https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=platform_connect_considerations_soql.htm&type=0&language=en_US)